# Flask - stop a function associated to a route

Tags: python, flask

I state that web development is not my main topic.

I am developing a web application with **python** and **flask** but I have a problem: I cannot stop the function associated to a route when I call another route.

For simplicity we assume this scenario:

- **BUTTON A** -> associated route */buttonA* and function *buttonA()*
- **BUTTON B** -> associated route */buttonB* and function *buttonB()*

I first click on *buttonA*.
Function buttonA() is executed which at the end redirects me to a page on page **A**.
While the buttonA() function is running, I click on *buttonB*. Button B takes me to page **B**.

Currently if I click *buttonA* first and then *buttonB*, buttonB() function is only executed after the buttonA() function is finished.

Is there any way to avoid this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you want to run two functions at the same time or stop the running function and run the other function?

Comment: I want stop the first one.